# question on vertical tangent

Tags: derivatives

Why do we call vertical tangent as tangent, doessn't it crosses the curve from one side to the other side of the curve at x=0?

$f(x)=x^{1/3}$

Thanks.

Comment: Being vertical is not particularly relevant. You could pose the same question for the horizontal tangent to $f(x)=x^3$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Tangent line is the limit of section lines. When it cuts the graph it's called *inflexion point*.

Comment: @Berci so there always is a real tangent at an inflection point and also at Cusp.